# Angular folder structure for CMS

Tags: angularjs, content-management-system, opencart

i’ve juz started with angular, i saw this post on folder structuring http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-growth-structure/

This is what my folder looks like which i'm building for an eCommerce site frontend:

```
.
├── index.html
├── css
├── images
├── fonts
├── scripts
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── directives
│   │   ├── search
│   │   ├── image-slider
│   │   ├── faq
│   │   └── form
│   └── api
└── templates
    ├── nav.html
    ├── footer.html
    └── page
        ├── full.html
        └── sidebar-right.html
```

Is there any better way/practice that you would do for this?
My greatest worry would be moving on into integrations with a CMS(opencart/magento) folder structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dir structure looks fine, however you may run into issues while integrating with any CMS as they put their views on a different directory.

> **Workaround**: Once you do integrate Magento or some random CMS, move your views to the CMS's view folder and make sure you serve index.html with your angular from the CMS.

Hope I could help.

Comment: So within the CMS's model, view, controller folders, my main workaround will still be within the view folder itself correct?

Comment: hmm it would appear to me to be that way, you can keep your scripts in your cms's assets directory and the views in your cms's views or public directory, I'm not sure which though... You'll have to try it out

Comment: yeah i would definitely need to experiment this out further, anyways thx for your heads up. Now i'm getting a clearer picture on where i'm heading. :)